# THREE.Object3D : How to disable Raycast for Object, not Material?

Tags: three.js

So the common sense seems to be to set the object's  material visibility to false.

So this does not work when I have countless of Objects which share the same Material. but I want to disable SOME of them, according to their data.

with

```
Object.visible = false;
```

i can hide them, but they are still selectable.

```
Object.Material.visible = false
```

hides ALL THE OBJECTS, because their shared Material is set invisible.

Can this be done?

I am not creating those Objects, so no chance to create multiple materials. I can only work with the objects I obtain which share the same Material and need to be hidden

Comment: Looking at the source it seems that visibility (of object or material) does not impact the raycast. Depending on what your end goal is you can add a custom field to the objects and then filter the intersections AFTER raycasting or maintain a separate list of objects that you know you'll want to raycast against.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution 1: Manually filtering raycast candidates and results

It doesn't look like there is any built in field to achieve what you want but you should be able to implement a similar behavior by manually filtering the list of objects to raycast against. Here's an idea for how you might do that:

```
// scene with lots of nested objects
const scene, raycaster;

// ...

// Gather up which objects to try to raycast against based on
// a set of conditions
const raycastList = [];
scene.traverse(c => {
    if (c.isMesh && !c.disableRaycast) {
        raycastList.push(c);
    }
});

// raycast against only the items in the array
const intersections = raycaster.raycastObjects(raycastList);
```

If you want to filter based on meshes parents `disableRaycast`field then you can create a custom traverse function that lets you keep track of a parents disabled state stop traversal early.

If you already know which objects should or shouldn't be raycasted against ahead of time you could just pre-create that list and keep it around.

EDIT

#### Solution 2: Overriding and making a custom Mesh.raycast() function

If you don't have access to modify the raycast code then you could create a "DeactivateableRaycastMesh" class that implements a custom raycast method and allows you to enable or disable whether it returns raycast hits.

```
class DeactivateableRaycastMesh extends THREE.Mesh {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.raycastEnabled = true;
    }

    raycast(...args) {
        if (!this.raycastEnabled) return;
        super.raycast(...args);
    }

}
```

If you need this functionality on *every* mesh and not just the ones you've created then you could modify the   `THREE.Mesh.prototype` to add the above functionality to all meshes. However this isn't recommended.

```
const originalRaycast = THREE.Mesh.prototype.raycast;
THREE.Mesh.prototype.raycast = function(...args) {
    if (!this.raycastEnabled) return;
    originalRaycast.call(this, ...args);
}
```

Comment: I dont have access to this. I can just alter existing objects in scene graph!

Comment: by not having access i mean i dont call the raycaster in my codebase. i am trying to alter a scene of an existing app based on three. but disableRaycast sounds interesting maybe!

Comment: If you don't have to modify the raycast logic then you could take a look at the second solution I edited the post above to include, which should afford the behavior you're talking about.